# Overriding method (early join) and putting "null"

Tags: java, overriding

Good morning all.
I thought I knew what does overriding and overloading means and tried to explain it to my friend. Everything was good, but when i came home i decided to write this example.

```
    public class Car{

    public void say(){
        System.out.println("Dodge");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Car c = new Dodge();
        new Car().print(c);
    }
    public void print(Car t){
        System.out.println("Car");
    }
    public void print(Dodge b){
        System.out.println("Dodge");
    }
}

class Dodge extends Car{
    public void say(){
        System.out.println("Dodge");
    }
}
```

It's obvious that if we run this code: "Car" will be the output. Because compiler will find method which takes format object Car.
But what if we change main method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    new Car().print(null);
}
```

The output will be: "Dodge" and i can't figure out why? Can smb explain please?

P.S. I tried wrote also this code:

```
public class Car{

public void say(){
    System.out.println("Dodge");
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Car().print(null);
}
public void print(BigInteger t){
    System.out.println("Car");
}
public void print(Double b){
    System.out.println("Dodge");
}
```

}
and Idea tells me that: 
**Ambiguous method call. Both print (BigInteger) in Car and
print (Double) in Car match**
This message is obvious. 
Does hierarchy influence on this and why? Please, tell me what I'm missing.

Comment: `Double` and `BigInteger` are unrelated class. Which method should be invoked for `null` where `null` can be used for either? The compiler doesn't know, do you? If yes, you should specify it with a cast.

Comment: nailed it^ you should put that as an answer though.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Yes, you are right but it doesn't explain why it prints `Dodge` in the second example.

Comment: @GIJoe Sorry, just noticed there are 3 examples. In the second, `Dodge` and `Car` are related and `Dodge` is more specific, so that one is chosen.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Right, but I don't get how you can just do `new Car().print(null);` and get `Dodge` as he says. He is creating a `Car` object, not `Dodge` object.

Comment: @GIJoe Because the `Car` class declares two overloaded methods. `Dodge` is a sub class of `Car`. It will therefore be more specific than `Car` and therefore be chose with a `null` argument. In the case of `Double` and `BigInteger`, the classes are unrelated and therefore at the same object hierarchy level. There's nothing to distinguish them. Therefore none is more specific.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Interesting. Ok.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Yup, BigInteger and Double examples are easy. I didn't know Java takes the subclass as more "specific".

Comment: @GIJoe There's a whole rule set for deciding most specific. Keppil's answer has a link to it I think.

Comment: Thank you all guys, that was interesting discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java always tries to go for the most specific match when deciding which method to invoke. See [JLS Section 15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2), in particular the part

> *If no method applicable by subtyping is found, the search for applicable methods continues with phase 2 (§15.12.2.3).
>
>    Otherwise, the most specific method (§15.12.2.5) is chosen among the methods that are applicable by subtyping.*

In your first example with argument `null`, `Dodge` is the most specific argument match since it inherits from `Car`, so no problems there.
In your last example however, there is no clear winner since none of the candidates `Double` and `BigInteger` inherit from the other one. Hence, you get the ambiguity error.

Comment: Why does the second example print `Dodge` if `null` is used (there are three examples)

Comment: @GIJoe: I only commented on the `null` examples, since OP was only confused with those. I'll edit to make it clearer.

Comment: He changed it to say the first example passes an object derived from Dodge, second example creates a new Car and passes null to print (yet it matches Dodge? and not Car?), third passes null with print methods that only take BigInteger and Double.

Comment: @GIJoe: Both possible `print` methods are in the `Car` class in both examples, so I think I have covered both situations in my answer.